Marker and popup in zoom and zoom out and Show/Hide in Leaflet
I have a JavaScript code that displays a number of representatives on a map view based on location
I specified that they should be displayed on every zoom in on the map
But they do not hide when zoomed out
 var objList = '<?php echo($simples);?>';
        var obj = JSON.parse(objList);
        var id_simple='';
        var name_simple='';
        var title_work_logo_simple='';
        var lat_simple='';
        var lon_simple='';
        var family_simple;
        var mobile_simple;
        var state_name_simple='';
        $.each( obj, function(key1, value ) {
            $.each( value, function( key3, value2 ) {
                if(key3 === 'id'){id_simple = value2;}
                if(key3 === 'lat'){lat_simple = value2;}
                if(key3 === 'lon'){lon_simple = value2;}
                if(key3 === 'name'){name_simple = value2;}
                if(key3 === 'last_name'){family_simple = value2;}
                if(key3 === 'mobile'){mobile_simple = value2;}
                if(key3 === 'state_name'){state_name_simple = value2;}
                if(key3 === 'title_work_logo'){title_work_logo_simple = value2;}
            });
            var greenIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: '/img/agent.png',
                iconSize:     [80, 26], // size of the icon

            });
            map.on('zoomend', function(){
                if(map.getZoom() > 8){
                    if(lat_simple !=='' && lon_simple !==''){
                        L.marker([lat_simple, lon_simple], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("<a href=\"/branch-single/" + id_simple + "/"+ state_name_simple +"-"+ family_simple +"\"><b>"+ name_simple +' '+ family_simple+"</b><br /><img class='agent-logo' src='/photo/agent-simple-logo/"+ title_work_logo_simple +"'><br />"+ mobile_simple + "</a>");
                        ;
                    }
                }
                else if(map.getZoom() < 7) {
                   

                }
            });


        });

I want them to disappear when the map zooms out.

If you have reference to those added markers you can do whatever you want like remove them , add them again, inspect them etc.
let arrayOfMarkers = [];

 map.on('zoomend', function(){
    if(map.getZoom() > 8){
        if(lat_simple !=='' && lon_simple !==''){
            let marker = L.marker([lat_simple, lon_simple], {icon: greenIcon});
            arrayOfMarkers.push(marker);
            marker.addTo(map).bindPopup("<a href=\"/branch-single/" + id_simple + "/"+ state_name_simple +"-"+ family_simple +"\"><b>"+ name_simple +' '+ family_simple+"</b><br /><img class='agent-logo' src='/photo/agent-simple-logo/"+ title_work_logo_simple +"'><br />"+ mobile_simple + "</a>");
        }
    }
    else if(map.getZoom() < 7) {
       arrayOfMarkers.forEach(marker => marker.remove())

    }
});

